# sequence and their arithmetic means

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can it happen that $s_n>0$ and that $\limsup s_n=\infty$, although $\lim \sigma_n=0$ where $\sigma_n=\dfrac{s_0+s_1+\dots+s_n}{n+1}$.

I want to take such sequence: $s_n$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is not perfect square and $1+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ if $n$ is perfect square. How to prove that $\lim \sigma_n=0$ or $\lim \sigma_n\neq0$?

**P.S.** I know that there are other examples but I'm interested in this sequence. Can anyone explain my question?

Comment: Just overestimate. $s_1 + \dotsc + s_n$ is less than $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ plus $\sum\limits_{m^2 \leqslant n} s_{m^2}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I have the same estimate. But how to overestime these sums? The first sum is less that $\ln n+1$. But what about the second sum?

Comment: How many of the $H_m$ are there, and how large is the largest of them?

Comment: @DanielFischer, there are $[\sqrt{n}]$ harmonic numbers in this sum and the largest is $H_{[\sqrt{n}]}$.

Comment: Cool, so you have a nice overestimate, right?

Comment: Yeah! So our $n$th partial sum is less than $\ln n+1+\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\ln n}{2}+1\right)$. So we got that $\sigma_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}s_k$ tends to zero if $n\to \infty$, right?

Comment: @DanielFischer, It's exercise from baby Rudin from third chapter but here I used estimates for harmonic numbers by natural logariphm. So my sequence is implies to exercise?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but your sequence satisfies $\limsup s_n = +\infty$ and $\lim \sigma_n = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, what do not you understand? My last estimate?

Comment: The connection between it being an exercise from chapter 3 of Rudin's PMA and estimating harmonic numbers by logarithms. If there is any connection.

Comment: Maybe here I am using that $\frac{\ln n}{n^{\delta}}\to 0$ if $n\to\infty$ and for any $\delta>0$. An logarithms is undefined. Rudin deines them in chapter 8.

Comment: You just need that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} H_n \to 0$. You can prove that ad hoc if need be, without having ever heard of logarithms.

Comment: @DanielFischer, What means "ad hoc"? How it can be proven?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I know how to prove that $H_n/n\to 0$ but i have not any ideas when denominator is $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: You could for example show that $k^{-2/3} < 3\bigl(k^{1/3} - (k-1)^{1/3}\bigr)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I showed this. But I don't see any relation between this inequality and what I need. Maybe we must sum these inequalities?

Comment: $\frac{1}{k} \leqslant \frac{1}{k^{2/3}}$. So $\sum_{k = 1}^m \frac{1}{k} \leqslant \sum_{k = 1}^m \frac{1}{k^{2/3}} \leqslant \,?$

Comment: @DanielFischer, $0<\frac{H_n}{\sqrt{n}}\leqslant \frac{3\sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt[6]{n}}\to 0$. Hence $\frac{H_n}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$. Right?

Comment: @DanielFischer, Thank you very much!